# Django's runscript: No (valid) module for script 'filename' found

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a script from the Django shell using the Django-extension [RunScript](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html). I have done this before and but it refuses to recognize my new script:

```
(env) mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/GP/GP $ python manage.py runscript fill_in_random_variants
No (valid) module for script 'fill_in_random_variants' found
Try running with a higher verbosity level like: -v2 or -v3
```

While running any other script works fine:

```
(env) mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/GP/GP $ python manage.py runscript fill_in_variants
Success! At least, there were no errors.
```

I have double checked that the file exists, including renaming it to something else. I have also tried running the command with non-existent script names:

```
(env) mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/GP/GP $ python manage.py runscript thisfiledoesntexist
No (valid) module for script 'thisfiledoesntexist' found
Try running with a higher verbosity level like: -v2 or -v3
```

and the error is the same.

Why can't RunScript find my file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

RunScript has confusing error messages. It gives the same error for when it can't find a script at all and when there's an import error in the script.

Here's an example script to produce the error:

```
import nonexistrentpackage

def run():
    print("Test")
```

The example has the only stated requirement for scripts, namely a `run` function.

Save this as `test_script.py` in a scripts folder (such as `project root/your app/scripts/test_script.py`). Then try to run it:

```
(env) mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/GP/GP $ python manage.py runscript test_script
No (valid) module for script 'test_script' found
Try running with a higher verbosity level like: -v2 or -v3
```

Which is the same error as the file not found one. Now outcomment the import line and try again:

```
(env) mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/GP/GP $ python manage.py runscript test_script
Test
```

As far as I know, the only way to tell the errors apart is to use the verbose (-v2) command line option and then look at the *first* (scroll up) error returned:

```
(env) mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/GP/GP $ python manage.py runscript test_script -v2
Check for www.scripts.test_script
Cannot import module 'www.scripts.test_script': No module named 'nonexistrentpackage'.
Check for django.contrib.admin.scripts.test_script
Cannot import module 'django.contrib.admin.scripts.test_script': No module named 'django.contrib.admin.scripts'.
Check for django.contrib.auth.scripts.test_script
Cannot import module 'django.contrib.auth.scripts.test_script': No module named 'django.contrib.auth.scripts'.
Check for django.contrib.contenttypes.scripts.test_script
Cannot import module 'django.contrib.contenttypes.scripts.test_script': No module named 'django.contrib.contenttypes.scripts'.
Check for django.contrib.sessions.scripts.test_script
Cannot import module 'django.contrib.sessions.scripts.test_script': No module named 'django.contrib.sessions.scripts'.
Check for django.contrib.messages.scripts.test_script
Cannot import module 'django.contrib.messages.scripts.test_script': No module named 'django.contrib.messages.scripts'.
Check for django.contrib.staticfiles.scripts.test_script
Cannot import module 'django.contrib.staticfiles.scripts.test_script': No module named 'django.contrib.staticfiles.scripts'.
Check for django_extensions.scripts.test_script
Cannot import module 'django_extensions.scripts.test_script': No module named 'django_extensions.scripts'.
Check for scripts.test_script
Cannot import module 'scripts.test_script': No module named 'scripts'.
No (valid) module for script 'test_script' found
```

where we can see the crucial line:

```
No module named 'nonexistrentpackage'.
```

The commonality of the errors seems to be because the extension runs the script using `import`. It would be more sensible if it first checked for the existence of the file using [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) and if not found, the threw a more sensible error message.

Answer (score 8):

Another Important thing to watchout for

**No .py should be given, just the name of the file ( script )**

```
 python3 manage.py runscript -v3 scriptname;
```

Comment: Kudos. Ditching the .py worked for me.

Comment: Although, it's clearly shown in the documentation that we are supposed to run the script without extension (.py), we end up using a script with extension :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I spend an hour to find out what is the problem. However, the solution is very simple. In my case, I had the following modules imported in my script.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
```

I was using virtualenv and I forgot to install **openpyxl**.

I have installed opnepyxl using pip.

> pip install openpyxl

So please make sure all of your imported modules are installed.

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
python manage.py shell < scripts/{$filename$}
```

It should work the same and be easier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not running the runscript command correctly.

**Scenario A**: You script is inside the scripts folder
i.e.

```
   scripts
     test.py
```

run `python manage.py runscript test`

**Scenario B**: Your script is inside a sub directory
i.e

```
   scripts
     data
       data.py
```

run `python manage.py runscript scripts.data.data`

**Scenario C**:
Your scrips is in a folder that isn't scripts. Follow instructions in scenario B above.

Answer (score 0):

You can verificate if the name of your script folder is correctly write. the folder name can be "scripts" with "s" to the end. I've forget him and a have a problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have another option for this:

I named the script filename `xx_v1.6.0.py`.

```bash
python manage.py runscript xx_v1.6.0
# No (valid) module for script 'xx_v1.6.0' found
# Try running with a higher verbosity level like: -v2 or -v3
```

After I changed filename to `xx.py`.

```bash
python manage.py runscript xx
```

Everything works fine.